# Unknown Power showing up in Formula

Tags: evaluation, formatting

I have the following worksheet below.

[image]

(I took a screen shot because I didn't know how to type the code for the particular function).  Circled in red are powers that shouldn't be there and yet they show up.  They seems to be raising the part in parentheses to the particular $k$ value defined by $p[n,k]$.  Can anyone tell me why this is the case?

Edit:  Here is the copied and pasted code.  Note that I actually corrected my formula by simply raising the parentheses expression to the $1/k$ power, but I'm still confused as to why it's being raised to the $k$ in the first place.

```
-Product[(n + i)^(Floor[k/i] - 1)*(p[n, 0] + 
          Sum[(Product[n + k + 1 - i, {i, 1, j}]/
                 Product[(n + i)^Floor[j/i], {i, 1, j}])*p[n, j], 
            {j, 1, k - 1}]), {i, 1, k}]
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the code from the Notebook; it will look like a mess but it should be usable anyway.  I'll try to improve the formatting from there.

Comment: Okay.  Give me a minute.

Comment: The code you edited.  Is this the fixed version?

Comment: No, that's just the formatting for easy copy&paste for others.  My answer is below.

Comment: You use index $i$ two times: one in the outer product and one in the inner product. The inner one shades the effect of the outer one.

Comment: so should I just change the index to something arbitrarily different?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. You do not want nested products. Just put the first product in parentheses! :-)

Comment: @ybeltukov that worked like a charm...it also calculates like 100x faster too!!

Answer (score 2):

Looking again at the image I realize you are using a strange construct:

```
p[n, 0] = p[n_, 0] := 1
p[n, 0] = p[n_, 1] := -1
p[n, k] = p[n_, k_] := (* body *)
```

I strongly suspect that this is not what you want.  Instead I believe you are attempting to set up [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html), in which case I believe you need to change these to:

```
p[n_, 0] = 1;
p[n_, 1] = -1;
p[n_, k_] := p[n, k] = (*body*)
```

However this change does not affect the behavior that is the subject of your post.  That behavior seems to be unrelated to the recursive use of `p` entirely:

```
With[{n = x, k = 3},
 -Product[(n + i)^(Floor[k/i] - 1)*(+ 
           Sum[(Product[n + k + 1 - i, {i, 1, j}]/
                 Product[(n + i)^Floor[j/i], {i, 1, j}]), 
             {j, 1, k - 1}]), {i, 1, k}]
]
```

> $-(x+1)^2 \left(\frac{x+3}{x+1}+\frac{x+3}{(x+1)^2}\right)^3$

Do you believe this output is incorrect, and if so, why?

Comment: p[n,1]=-1, not 1.  Also, I think I need to use Simplify to condense the polynomial.  If it helps, I calculated all of these by hand and confirmed what I need so I know that P[n,2]=1, and p[n,3]=n-1.

Comment: The second parentheses should not be raised to the 3rd power.  It shouldn't be raised to any power.

Comment: @Eleven Sorry, my mistake.  I'll correct that, but I don't think it changes the second part of my answer.

Comment: @Eleven Please consider the example where I removed the `p[_, _]` terms entirely; do you believe it is incorrect, and if so, how/why?

Comment: I cut and paste it into a new notebook and ran it and it is not correct.  that power still shows up

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: As best I can tell the power of 3 appears to be correct. Subsitutiting `x` for a variety of positive integer values gives the same results as numerically computing the product of sums. Could you explain why you think it might be wrong?

Comment: Because I hand calculated the results over the last couple of days for $k$ up to 6.  I know they are correct from other mathematica calculations.  Ultimately I got the correct advice from @ybeltukov above